# How do I achieve this BottomSheet customization like this?

Tags: flutter, flutter-widget

How do I make BottomSheet like this in Flutter? Specifically the boldge where arrow is?

[image]

Comment: You can do that with a CustomClipper using a CustomPath. Please share what you have tried so far, so we can help you with that.

Comment: Honestly I have no idea how to use Clipper. I can only make bottom sheet with rounded corners. I was hoping someone will explain me how to that arrow things in middle.

Comment: https://www.developerlibs.com/2019/08/flutter-draw-custom-shaps-clip-path.html There you have an article that can help get you started. Please keep in mind we cannot do the job for you. Anyway if you get stuck with something specific we will be glad to help you :)

Comment: Thank you I will check it out. This is not for job, I'm still learning and trying to make ui I saw on dribbble :)

Comment: You're welcome! Making dribbble designs is a great way to learn! Best wishes

Answer (score 0):

It can be solved by setting the background color of showModalBottomSheet, transparent
backgroundColor: Colors.transparent,and use a cliper or rounded shape in it.